# A question of strict inequality and Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis

Question:
Let $f : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x)\ge0$ for all
$x \in [a, b]$ and such that $f(c) \gt 0$ for some $c \in [a, b]$. Prove that
$ \int^a_b  f > 0$.

What I have determined so far is that since $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, it follows that $f\in \mathbb{R}_{[a,b]}$ (Riemann Integrable). It also follows that since $\forall x \in [a,b]$, $f(x)\ge0$, then $\int^a_bf\ge0$.

Now I need to show that this is a strict inequality. I suspect I have to use the fact that $f(c) \gt 0$ for some $c \in [a, b]$

My thought was that since $f(c) > 0$, $f(b)\ge0$, and $f(a) \ge 0$, then $\int^b _a f = (\int^c_a f + \int^b_cf) \gt 0$ by virtue of the fact that $a \neq b$ and since $c \in [a,b]$, possibly $c=a$ or $c=b$ but not both. So either $\int^c_a f\gt0$ or $\int^b_cf\gt0$. So it must be that $\int^b _a f = (\int^c_a f + \int^b_cf) \gt 0$.

This is probably wrong so any corrections and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to continuity, since $f(c)>0$,  you must have an entire neighborhood of $c$ that is bounded away from 0 (neighborhood within the domain $[a,b]$).

We can express that neighborhood as for some $\epsilon>0$,  $(c-\epsilon ,c+\epsilon )\cap [a,b]$.  You may want to take some cases on whether $c=a,c=b$ just for the one sided $[a,b]$,  but the important part of the argument is that we have an entire open, positive length interval that's a subset of $[a,b]$ where $f>0$.  Pick two points inside that open interval, so that the function is strictly positive inside the closed interval.   Now, divide your integral from $[a,b]$  into integrals inside the closed interval where it's strictly positive and the other 1 or 2 regions. (depending on whether you're in the middle, left, or right).

Since f is strictly positive on the little one, the integral is strictly positive. Add to that numbers that are at least 0, and you are still strictly positive.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you are showing that there is some closed interval in [a,b] on which the function is strictly positive and then anything outside of that on [a,b] is already greater than or equal to zero. So then the whole interval is greater than 0 in terms of the integral.

Comment: That's correct, Nid.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f(c) > 0$, show that by continuity of $f$, $f(x) > \frac{f(c)}{2}$ for all $x$ in a closed interval $[\alpha,\beta]$ containing $c$. Then as $f \ge 0$, $$\int_a^b f \ge \int_\alpha^\beta f \ge \frac{f(c)}{2}(\beta - \alpha) > 0.$$